# openCV Gaussian blur/smoothing of 3D Matrix/Histogram

Tags: opencv, 3d, histogram, blur, gaussian

I have a (3D) Histogram which I like to apply Gaussian smoothing on:

```
cv::MatND Hist;
```

In the 1D and 2D cases I blur it via:

```
cv::GaussianBlur(Hist, Hist, cv::Size(1,3), 1.0);// 1D case
cv::GaussianBlur(Hist, Hist, cv::Size(3,3), 1.0);// 2D case
```

But I struggle to apply Gaussian blurring in the 3D case.

Has anyone got an idea how to attempt this?

Answer (score 3):

Try use separable kernels like shown here:
http://www.programming-techniques.com/2013/03/gaussian-blurring-using-separable.html