# How to apply Gaussian blur to 3d Matrix?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

My question is exactly same as in this link. But, I want to apply blurring, using GaussianBlur function only. While the answer provided apply it using its own code.

[openCV Gaussian blur/smoothing of 3D Matrix/Histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020438/opencv-gaussian-blur-smoothing-of-3d-matrix-histogram)

I have written following code. Here dimension of histogram is tbucket*xbucket*ybucket. First, I had created Matrix temp_blur for all the tbucket and apply GaussianBlur function on it in dimension xbucket and dimension ybucket seperately. Next, I had created Matrix for tbucket*ybucket for all the xbucket and apply GaussianBlur function on dimension tbucket. Is it the correct way to do it?

```
void Histogram::blur_(int sigma1,int sigma2){
    Mat temp_blur;
    for(int i=0;i<tbucket;i++){
        temp_blur=Mat(xbucket,ybucket,CV_32F);
        for(int j=0;j<xbucket;j++){
            for(int k=0;k<ybucket;k++){
                temp_blur.at<float>(j,k)=values[i][j][k];
            }
        }
        GaussianBlur(temp_blur,temp_blur,Size(1,2*sigma1+1),sigma1,sigma1); //make sure its correct, 2D broken to 1D
        GaussianBlur(temp_blur,temp_blur,Size(2*sigma2+1,1),sigma2,sigma2); 
        for(int j=0;j<xbucket;j++){
            for(int k=0;k<ybucket;k++){
                values[i][j][k]=temp_blur.at<float>(j,k);
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<xbucket;i++){
        temp_blur=Mat(tbucket,ybucket,CV_32F);
        for(int j=0;j<tbucket;j++){
            for(int k=0;k<ybucket;k++){
                temp_blur.at<float>(j,k)=values[j][i][k];
            }
        }
        GaussianBlur(temp_blur,temp_blur,Size(1,2*sigma1+1),sigma1,sigma1); //make sure its correct, 2D broken to 1D
        GaussianBlur(temp_blur,temp_blur,Size(2*sigma2+1,1),sigma2,sigma2); 
        for(int j=0;j<tbucket;j++){
            for(int k=0;k<ybucket;k++){
                values[j][i][k]=temp_blur.at<float>(j,k);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what are you asking?  You want to apply blurring using Gaussian kernels... yet the link you provided us does just that.  Do you want to implement the kernel **yourself**?

Comment: I want to apply blurring by using GuassianBlur function, like for 2D its, cv::GaussianBlur(Hist, Hist, cv::Size(3,3), 1.0). What it will be for 3D?

Comment: You can take 2D slices of your 3D matrix and apply a `GaussianBlur` to each of those slices.  Starting from the first column, create a 2D matrix so that it takes all of the first columns for each of the channels down to the last channel.  Gaussian Blur, then repeat for the second column and go all of the way to the end.  You'll have to repeat this for all of the rows.